# Jquery select previous class

Tags: jquery

I´ve tried it with things like this, many other variants for like 2 hours...read many threads on SO but couldn´t find what i was searching for...

Ive got an structure like this: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WHhGM/)

```
<tr><td></td><td><select name="startTime[]" class="startTime"></select></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><select name="endTime[]" class="endTime"></select></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><select name="startTime[]" class="startTime"></select></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><select name="endTime[]" class="endTime"></select></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><select name="startTime[]" class="startTime"></select></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><select name="endTime[]" class="endTime"></select></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><select name="startTime[]" class="startTime"></select></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><select name="endTime[]" class="endTime"></select></td></tr>

            <script>
            $( ".endTime" ).change(function() {

                $(this).prevUntil('.startTime:first').addClass('pink');
                //$(this).prev(".startTime").addClass('pink');
//$('.endTime').prev('.startTime').addClass('pink');
                //$(this).prevAll('.startTime:first');

            });
            </script>
            <style>
                .pink{background-color: pink;}
            </style>
```

But i can´t figure out how to do it...put in some code that won´t work for me, i´ve tried a lot more combinations....

What i want: In the end i want to get the value from the field endtime and starttime, the addClass is just there to show that something should happen then....

Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: Could you please explain the question in some more detail?

Comment: Won't just using $(this).parents(".className") work?

Comment: Your classes are nested in several layers of table elements, you have to account for those as well.

Comment: prevUntil only works with siblings. So there's no .startTime in the same TD as endTime

Comment: @Fenixp didn´t work for me, tried it before, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to try

```
$(this).closest('tr').prev().find('.startTime').addClass('pink');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3APhH/)

Comment: Worked...yeah I did it wrong the whole time...thank you for your time. +1 and accept.

Answer (score 1):

try following:

```
$(this).closest('tr').prevAll().find('.startTime').addClass('pink');
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3APhH/2/

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at what [prevUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/) actually does:

> Get all preceding siblings

Your select has no siblings. It's the only child of the enclosing `<td>`. What you want is to traverse the DOM outwards to the nearest `<tr>`, get it's previous sibling, and then find your `<select>` inside.

```
$(this)
    .closest('tr')      // Find ancestor <tr> that is closest, ...
    .prev()             // ... then find its predecessor...
    .find('.startTime') // ... inside that predecessor, find the element with class `startTime` ...
    .addClass('pink');  // ... and finally colour it.
```

I think it gets a lot clearer if you tidy up/indent your HTML markup somewhat:

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <select name="startTime[]" class="startTime"></select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <select name="endTime[]" class="endTime"></select>
    </td>
</tr>
```